# NodeJS JSON error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

New to asynchronous programming here.

I am trying to fetch JSON data and parse it in node. However for some reason, I keep getting the error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function`

```
fetch(url).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(json) {
    jsonObj=JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(json);
    console.log("HELLO");
    console.log(jsonObj.id);
});
```

JSON data when `jsonObj=JSON.parse(json);` is commented out:

```
[ { id: 1,
    url: 'http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1/under-the-dome',
    name: 'Under the Dome',
    type: 'Scripted',
    language: 'English',
    genres: [ 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Thriller' ],
    status: 'Ended',
    runtime: 60,
    premiered: '2013-06-24',
    schedule: { time: '22:00', days: [Object] },
    rating: { average: 6.6 },
    weight: 0,
    network: { id: 2, name: 'CBS', country: [Object] },
    webChannel: null,
    externals: { tvrage: 25988, thetvdb: 264492, imdb: 'tt1553656' },
    image: 
     { medium: 'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/1.jpg',
       original: 'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/0/1.jpg' },
    summary: '<p>Inhabitants must deal with surviving the post-apocalyptic conditions</p>',
    updated: 1490211618,
    _links: { self: [Object], previousepisode: [Object] } }, ... 140 more items
```

Comment: Can you show the output of your console.log

Comment: If `res.json()` returns JSON data, then why are you also calling `JSON.parse` on it?

Comment: Post the output

Comment: @AlexYoung — JSON.parse converts JSON data into a JavaScript data structure.

Comment: I was parsing it wrong. @AlexYoung pointed out the solution. Previously I had my parse before the `return` line. Since it is already in JSON format, I do not have to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is an indication of that you have redefined the JSON object itself -- something like this;

```
$ node
> a='{"a":7}'
'{"a":7}'
> JSON.parse(a)
{ a: 7 }
> JSON=7
7
> JSON.parse(a)
TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function
```

Check to see what the value of JSON and JSON.parse and I bet it is not a function